# One view for two models: use a base model class to make it easier?

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I am having this scenario:

- A website for managing hotels.
- Another kind of Hotel model has been added over the course of the project, so now they are two.
- Now the boss wants the list of Hotels to include both kinds of Hotels.

I was thinking of the following possible solutions:

1. Invent a superclass containing the common properties needed to display in the list of Hotels, and override appropriately.
2. Hack my way in the view. It has one loop now, producing HTML code on the way (obviously). If this works, there will be two loops.

The problem I see with approach #1 is this: "Hotel1 extends BaseHotel1", "Hotel2 extends BaseHotel2". So OK, I will create a superclass, then what?

The problem with approach #2 is this: I am still far from a "pro" Symfony developer and I am not sure the view in question will have access to more than one model methods at all. Maybe render-partials from another module would work?

So, how do I do this? Do you think the problems I listed are easy to solve? Do you see another approaches?

If so, please share your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: How similar are the 2 hotel models? Do they contain a lot of overlapping fields?

Comment: They do. They have 8 similar properties -- just with different column names in the DB. The second Hotel model has some more properties, but they are happily not relevant to the action of listing Hotels. I have full control on the project at the moment and I can probably merge the tables/models. Curious about other alternatives, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've tagged your question Propel, but I'd look into using [Doctrine inheritance](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/inheritance/en) here - if there is a Propel equivalent that is - either the 'concrete' or 'column aggregation' (depending on how you want to store your data).  Essentially you'd end up with a base `Hotel` class, which you'll then have eg `Hotel1` and `Hotel2` classes extending from.

This way you can have methods common to both models in the Hotel model and table classes, and then hotel-specific methods in the `Hotel1` and `Hotel2` classes.

**Edit:** Just found [the Propel equivalent](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/Inheritance) although this link is for Propel 1.5.  It looks as if Propel 1.3 only supports the 'simple' inheritance type however.

Comment: So it seems I have to merge the two DB tables.

Comment: Yes that's correct. By doing this, you can still keep your extended fields for `Hotel2` but also have methods that work across both classes, and also the ability to list all Hotels easily in the same list (and subsequently filter by `Hotel1` or `Hotel2` etc).

Comment: So let's be precise: I create an SQL script to create one bigger table (or make Propel generate it for me), I follow the steps given at this URL, then I devise 2 scripts to migrate the data from the original 2 tables to the new table, then fire it up and it works? ;)

Comment: Assuming your fingers are crossed as well, that sounds foolproof ;-) heh, I'd go with Propel creating the table first - that way you have the associated PHP to go with it and also the defined column names to work with. But yes, that should be the case... :-)

Comment: Okay, could you give me an URL pointing towards how to do this same thing via the "schema.yml" file? I would very much like to work with YAML for configurations, not with XML.

Comment: I am also thinking if I should just add the fields of Hotel2 to the Hotel1 for one simple reason: I don't want to code new controller and views for the new "omni-hotel". Any underwater stones I should be expecting, if I do that?

Comment: If you're going to combine both sets of data, then you could do away with the inheritance and just have the Hotel2 fields as optional items for Hotel1 entries.  And you'd end up with a 'Hotel' table, with maybe an indicator flag.  Maybe inheritance is just complicating matters too much here :-)

Comment: When I think of it, that seems like the best solution. It would save me the trouble of making new Controller/View. That way, I can just go and edit the existing C/V code and start experimenting almost immediately. Right. Diving nose-deep, and once I succeed, I will mark the answer!

Comment: Alright, job is done. Merged all Hotel2 properties into Hotel1 schema, moved some code from Hotel2 controller to Hotel1 controller, did a few small tweaks, and everything is OK. Thanks very much for the help! Marking this as the answer.

Comment: Great stuff - glad it went OK! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine provides a nice solution here. Have a look at the [column aggreation inheritance](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/cookbook/taking-advantage-of-column-aggregation-inheritance/en). Maybe Propel provides something similar to that, but I'm not familiar with propel…